# Replication establishing error between Hyper-V 2012R2 and 2016 (0x00002EFE)

Tags: hyper-v, hyper-v-server-2012-r2, hyper-v-server-2016

I have Active Directory scenario with bunch of Hyper-V Server 2012R2 and Hyper-V Server 2016 servers. I have configured Kerberos authentication on port 80, enabled on firewall.
 I Want to enable replication from Hyper-V Server 2012R2 to Hyper-V Server 2016 and Im immediately getting this error message connected with event. in eventlog:

Hyper-V failed to enable replication.
 Hyper-V failed to enable replication for virtual machine 'XXXXX': The connection with the server was terminated abnormally (0x00002EFE).

Log Name:      Microsoft-Windows-Hyper-V-VMMS-Admin
 Source:        Microsoft-Windows-Hyper-V-VMMS
 Date:          2. 2. 2017 22:19:29
 Event ID:      29212
 Task Category: None
 Level:         Error
 Keywords:
 User:          SYSTEM
 Computer:      HV02
 Description:
 The description for Event ID 29212 from source Microsoft-Windows-Hyper-V-VMMS cannot be found. Either the component that raises this event is not installed on your local computer or the installation is corrupted. You can install or repair the component on the local computer.

If the event originated on another computer, the display information had to be saved with the event.

The following information was included with the event:

%%2147943395
 0x800703E3

The locale specific resource for the desired message is not present

Event Xml:
 
   
     
     29212
     0
     2
     0
     0
     0x8000000000000000
     
     472
     
     
     Microsoft-Windows-Hyper-V-VMMS-Admin
     HV01
     
   
   
     
       %%2147943395
       0x800703E3

I cant find any info about that replication between 2012R2 and 2016 is or isnt possible...

Have you experienced that?

Best regards,
 Jan

Answer (score 1):

I have found the answer: HTTP communication in replication protocol is crafted proprietarily. So it is not the standard one.
In my Kerio Control, there is a IPS protection what kills the connection silently. I was created special firewall rule that is only for that commnunication and this rule is not using HTTP inspection module. 
From that point the replication starts working smoothly.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get it from 2012R2->2016 using certificate authentication. However, to enable the replication I had to use PowerShell instead of the GUI.

```
Enable-VMReplication VMName -ReplicaServerName NewServer -AuthenticationType Certificate -CertificateThumbprint AAABBBCCCC111222333 -ReplicaServerPort 443
```

However, I am not having issues since my 2012R2 Server has been upgraded to 2016 going from 2016 Orig->2016 Upgraded. I'm getting the same error in the GUI and this with PowerShell.

```
Get-VMReplicationServer : You do not have the required permission to complete this task. Contact the administrator of the authorization policy for the computer 'HyperV-01'.
```